# Is this piece of code technically valid?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size, size-t

> ```
> int *b = arr, *e = arr + sz; // sz has a type of size_t
> while (b < e)
> {
>   // use *b
>   ++b;
> }
> ```

This is the code on C++ Primer. I'm quite new at C++, may I know what if `sz` is very large so an int can't hold, then should b and e be declared as a type of `size_t *`? I failed to find the answer for my question on Q&A. I'm quite confused at this part. Thank you! A relevant link is also welcome:-)

Comment: You seem to be confusing `int` with `int*`.  Adding a `size_t` to an `int*` is correct use of those types.  (Values might not be correct but the types are compatible and generally the same size).

Comment: This code is terrible. Throw this book out of the airlock.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! I got it already :-)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yeah I got what you mean, the convention in C++ should be for(auto iter=v.begin(); iter !=v.end();++iter). Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: No, this code is not valid. It uses the names `arr` and `sz` but they are not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` here is the type pointers point to and it's completely irrelevant here. Pointers have fixed size that does not depend on the pointed type, and that size will be at least the size of `size_t` (usually the same), so there's no danger.

Comment: Oh, I got it. int* and int are 2 different types so I can't compare the value of them. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, there is no guarantee that pointers and size_t are the same size.  Systems with "fat" pointers (that contain information about the permitted access) are likely to have pointers that are much larger than size_t.  Something like real-mode DOS with pointers represented as a 32-bit segment + offset, but only allowing objects which fit in a single segment, so size_t only needs to be 16 bits would also be legal.

Comment: Also, void * and char* are explicitly allowed to be bigger than struct*.  I can't remember what the guarantees are for int* (there probably aren't any - except that void* is "enough")